# Why do the CSS styles disappear when trying to change the className in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm building a simple react app, and in that I try to change the name of a div using the statement -

```
<div className={'changeTab ' + (page.login ? 'leftSide' : 'rightSide')} id="tab" ></div>
```

but the CSS part for it disappears when trying to do so. The rest of the page works fine so there's no linking problem to the CSS file. And when I try to use only the ID name instead of the class names, the styles work fine. Only when using the class names in the CSS the styles disappear and they don't even show on the developer tools when using inspect. The class names do appear in the class attribute in HTML part of the developer tools, but the CSS properties do not.

I use a simple useState Hook for the conditional statement -

```
    const [page, setPage] = useState([{
    login: true,
    signUp: false
  }])
```

Here's the CSS -

```
 #tab .changeTab .leftSide{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right,#4361ee,#4cc9f0);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0, 1.17, 0, 0.69);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#tab .changeTab .rightSide{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  margin-left: -50%;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0, 1.17, 0, 0.69);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I'm new to react so any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Please, put your code on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) so we can take a live look and help you.

Comment: Do you get any console errors? If so, post them in your question.

Comment: @Luka Here's the Codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/simpleloginsignup-zenw1

Comment: @Martin No I don't get any errors in the console, only a single type of warning about href attribute not having a valid value. I just put '#' in the href values as I don't need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your CSS specification seems to be flawed.

I believe that you are trying to apply styling to an element that has the id `tab` AND the class `changeTab` AND the class either `leftSide` OR `rightSide`.

Right now, you're telling your CSS to look for nested classes of the parent id `tab`.

That means your CSS is trying to find a child of id `tab` that has the class `changeTab` and then it again looks for a child of that element with the class `leftSide` or `rightSide`.

**Your CSS should be the following:**

```
#tab.changeTab.leftSide{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right,#4361ee,#4cc9f0);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0, 1.17, 0, 0.69);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#tab.changeTab.rightSide{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  margin-left: -50%;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0, 1.17, 0, 0.69);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Note how I removed the spacing in your CSS. This tells the CSS to look for an element that must have the id `tab` but also the classes `changeTab` and either `leftSide` or `rightSide`.

Comment: Yes that worked. I didn't know that spacing would mean nesting. Thanks a bunch for your help!